# Unable to display images in recyclerview~

Tags: android, json, firebase, android-recyclerview

I know this question has been asked many times and I have looked at all the solutions and tried them but my app still is unable to retrieve images.

Please help! First, no images are shown, second my app crashes. 
I'm pretty sure i'm lacking of something here but I cant quite figure out..
In my firebase database the headers are "Category" "Image" "Name".

```
    public class home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference category;
    TextView txtFullName;
    RecyclerView recycler_menu;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder> mFirebaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Menu");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Get PassUserFullName from MainActivity main
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String PassUserFullName = i.getStringExtra("PassUserFullName");

        //init Firebase
        /*database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        category = database.getReference("Category");*/

       category=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category");

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Show Name of User
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
/*        txtFullName = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);

        txtFullName.setText(""+PassUserFullName);
        *//*if {
            Toast.makeText(home.this, "User data field is null",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        */

        //Load Menu
        recycler_menu=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
        recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        loadMenu();
    }
    private void loadMenu(){
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,MenuViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(Category.class,R.layout.menu_item,MenuViewHolder.class,category) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MenuViewHolder viewHolder, Category model, int position) {
                viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.imageView);
                final Category clickItem = model;
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(home.this,""+clickItem.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_cart) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_orders) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_log_out) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}




public class Category {
    public String Image;
    public String Name;

    public Category(){
    }
    public Category(String Image, String Name){
        this.Image = Image;
        this.Name = Name;
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return Image;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setImage(String Image) {
        this.Image = Image;
    }
    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your Adapter code

Comment: ...also add the logs, please

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `RecyclerView` you are not passing the `list` data to your adapter only you used setAdapter. Pass list data to your RecyclerAdapter Class and get by cosntructor inside your Adapter class.

```
private void loadMenu(){
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,MenuViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(Category.class,R.layout.menu_item,MenuViewHolder.class,category) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MenuViewHolder viewHolder, Category model, int position) {
                viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.imageView);
                final Category clickItem = model;
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(home.this,""+clickItem.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        mFirebaseAdapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(home.this, yourList);
        recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

For more About RecyclerView Look into this : https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview/